# How do I put Ik controller rigs on Vroid models?

Tags: rigging

I've been working towards using Vroid models in animation, and have recently changed a few plans in my workflow, including moving to using Blender for the animation portion. Pose mode works well enough for this, but because of how the Vroid models are made its awkward to use. I have been advised that creating an Ik controller rig would be best for this, however I have not been able to find any guides that work for this. Does anyone know what the workflow would be specifically for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to import a lot of these models, my advice would be to delete the armature that comes with them and instead use [rigify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/introduction.html), but if you want to use the existing armature, because it has bones for hair and clothes, here's an example workflow showing just how to modify the left leg of the rig.

- Import the model using the gltf importer.
- Select the armature, helpfully called `Armature`, enable names in the armature viewport display and enter edit mode.
- Either enter wire frame mode, or select *In Front* in the armature viewport display
- There are a lot of bones with very long names, apparently related to clothing and hair.  You might want to look into an add-on like [bone layer manager](https://fin.gumroad.com/l/STdb) to help manage them.  It's a free add-on.  But however you do it, either move these bones to other layers or hide them so that working with the leg is easy.  In my example I hid everything but the three bones I need to work with.

This leaves my model looking like:

[image: Model showing armature with only left leg bones visible]

For the rest of this, I'll also hide the model.

1. For an IK rig to work, the foot bone needs to be separated from the leg bone. Select `J_Bip_L_Foot`. Go to the properties editor. In the bone tab, open the *Relations Tab*.  The *Parent* field should say `J_Bip_L_LowerLeg`.  Click the x to disconnect it.

[image: Relationship tab before disconnecting the parent]

2. You can leave the upper and lower leg disconnected, but Blender's IK solver works *much* better if you connect them, so

- Select the root of `J_Bip_L_LowerLeg`. The root is the sphere shape near the thick end of the bone.
- Move the 3D cursor to your selection (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)
- Select the tip of `J_Bip_L_UpperLeg`.  The root is the sphere shape near the skinny end of the bone.
- Snap the selection to the 3D Cursor (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>)

The armature should look like this:

[image: Armature with bones aligned]

- Select `J_Bip_L_LowerLeg` and enable *Connected* in the *Relationship* panel:

[image: bone tab showing parent is connected]

3. Now you're ready to set up the IK constraint.  With `J_Bip_L_LowerLeg` still selected go to *Pose* mode.  (Note: if you hid the other bones, as I did, rather than moving them, they'll reappear.) A new tab will appear in the properties editor. It is the *Bone Constraint Properties Tab*

- Select *Add Bone Constraint* and from the menu select *Inverse Kinematics*
  [image: Inverse Kinematics selected]
  4 Fill in the IK constraint
- Set Target to *Armature*. That will make a new box, *Bone* appear.  The bone target is the bone that will control your IK chain.  We want the foot, so select `J_Bip_L_Foot`.
- Set *Chain Length* to 2.  This tells the IK solver how many bones it should adjust when you move the target.  In this case we want the lower and upper leg, so we need two bones.

[image: The IK constraint filled out]

That's it.  Now, if you want to move the leg, simply select the foot bone in pose mode and move it.

This will work, but as you quickly discover, the knee flops all over the place.  We solve this by adding a *Pole Target* to the IK constraint.

- Go back to Edit mode.  We're going to add a new bone.
- Create a new bone.  The 3D cursor should still be at the knee joint, so the bone will appear there.
- Rotate it -90 degrees on the X axis. (Shortcut <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Move it forward on the Y axis and make it smaller, about the size of the foot bone.
- Give it a name that indicates it's the pole bone for the left leg.  I used `J_Bip_L_Leg_Pole` to be consistent
- Fill out the Pole field with *Armature* and your new name.

Your left leg should now look more or less like this:

[image: Left leg bones showing pole bone]

and your IK constraint like this:

[image: Filled out IK constraint with pole target]

Depending on the model you may have to move the knee joint slightly forward in edit mode to help the IK solver know which way the knee bends.